# MongoDB Ruby driver and IPV6 connection failure

Tags: ruby, mongodb, ipv6

I'm using MongoDBs on three different computers only accessible by IPV6.
I'm able to connect to those DBs using php5 driver, command line interface (with the option --ipv6) and an UI app called "MongoHUB".

The only driver unable to connect thru IPV6 is the ruby one.

Any tip using it, for example, does exist an option when creating a MongoClient by uri stating the address is an ipv6 one, as with command line ?

Answer (score 0):

The MongoDB Ruby driver doesn't support IPv6 yet (just an oversight/no one had requested it), but it will be fully supported in our next release.

Add yourself as a watcher to this ticket here to follow the progress:
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/RUBY-700